# how to run schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm trying to run db:migrate.
This fails however because one of the tables that one of the migrations is trying to update does not exist. I searched the codebase and this table is created in db/schema.rb.

How can I run schema.rb before db:migrate??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the schema load task:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

From `rake -T` (expurgated version):

```
rake db:schema:dump  # Create db/schema.rb file usable with any AR-supported DB
rake db:schema:load  # Load schema.rb file into DB
```