# RSpec/Rails : How to test column creation, and delete column after the test passed

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a controller function that add columns to table 'custom_fiels'.
Columns to add comes from table 'custom_field_descs'
I want to test that this function adds all expected columns to the table.

My test look like this :

```
describe 'GET /update_db' do
  let(:custom_field) { CustomField.create! valid_attributes }

  before :each do
    FactoryBot.create(:custom_field_desc)
    FactoryBot.create(:custom_field_desc, :type_a)
    FactoryBot.create(:custom_field_desc, :type_b)

    custom_field
  end

  after :each do
    # ...
  end

  it 'updates the database with new columns' do
    get custom_fields_update_db_path

    expect(custom_field.reload).to respond_to(:custom_1)
    expect(custom_field).to respond_to(:custom_2)
    expect(custom_field).to respond_to(:custom_3)
    expect(custom_field).to_not respond_to(:custom_4)
    expect(response).to redirect_to(custom_fields_url)
  end
end
```

The test pass, but I don't know how to remove columns from db after the test.
Datas are not removed after this test (the user, the custom field, etc)
The next time I throw the test, the columns are already there.
and all Tests do not pass because old datas are still in database.

I tried with DatabaseCleaner but it destroy only datas, not created columns.
I tried to add ActiveRecord::Base.connection.remove_column :custom_fields, :custom_1
in after:each but it does not delete columns.

Is it the wright way to test this ?

How can I delete the columns from db for the next test ?

Ruby 2.7
Rails 6
RSpec 4

Answer (score 0):

Slightly hacky, but you can [disable schema.rb dump during migrations in test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453267/how-to-disable-dbschemadump-for-migrations)

Then, you can just [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823252/how-to-run-schema-rb) the untouched schema.rb at RSpec launch (in spec_helper.rb).

Answer (score 0):

normally When we run tests our database cleaned by default after every test, but if your database still have the values please add the following line in your **rails_helper.rb** file created by Rspec.

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

and if you have already this line, just  make it true.